# javax.mail to jakarta.mail which one to use

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Both javax.mail and jakarta.mail is available for Java. Is javax.mail is getting deprecated? Should I be moving to jakarta.mail?

Thanks.

Comment: Java EE is renamed to [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/); the latter is newer. But which one you should use depends on the application server that you're going to deploy your application in, if it's a Java EE/Jakarta EE application. Find out what version your app server supports and use that version.

Answer (score 0):

I you've switched to the newer application server, you should probably use jakrta.mail